# how to start jboss for my local network

Tags: jboss

First question is: it seems like magic that one I run ./run.sh, I can turn off the computer, turn it back on again and still it knows about //localhost:8080/jmx-console/. I looked in the start up programs and I don't see any hint of it. How does it remember?

Never mind, the real question is I want the host to be my local LAN and not just localhost. I found I could do shutdown.sh and that would indeed shutdown the server such that //localhost:8080/jmx-console/ would no longer work. That is good, now the next step is to confine it to my LAN. I know I can use ./run.sh -b 0.0.0.0 but that opens it to the world. My computer is at 192.168.1.100 so I tried ./run.sh -b 192.168.1.0 which I would take to mean take addresses in the range 192.168.1.XXX. The server "started" but I can't get it to answer any calls and I couldn't get shutdown.sh to do anything.

I started ./run.sh again and it hooked up to the localhost. I don't know if it still has a memory of my ./run.sh -b 192.168.1.0 or not. If so, I'd like to get rid of it. In any case I'd like to know what the correct command should be.

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of jboss?

I use -b 127.0.0.1 on jboss 4

Comment: I am using dcm4chee which demands jboss-4.2.3.GA. (It won't work on later versions of jboss.) If you use -b 127.0.0.1 doesn't that take you back to localhost? I want a network to include all computers on my LAN (all 3 of them - a huge number!)

Comment: Wrom interpretation from my side. -b 0.0.0.0 should be correct then. Perhaps this is useful https://community.jboss.org/wiki/LimitAccessToCertainClients or deny internet access through the firewall.

Comment: My question is: can't I limit the access? -b 0.0.0.0 opens it up to ALL IPs. Can I limit it to a subnet using something like 192.168.1.0? There should be something in between localhost and the whole world.

Comment: I see in your link maybe something like -b 192.168.1.*, not exactly in that format, but at least it is something to try. If it were legal I would expect to open it up completely -b *.*.*.* which is clearly not the case.

Comment: By George it works! The answer is: ./run.sh -b 192.168.1.* I would have never guessed it, but it works! Thanks for your help.